# Control users status (connected/disconnected) in my Spring-Boot App with Keycloak

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, keycloak, status

I have a user-management `REST` application (Spring-Boot) integrated with `Keycloak`, and I would like to know if there is any way to see the status (***connected*** or ***disconnected***) of my clients.

I have in mind is to create a table in my database with an ***user-identifier*** and a boolean, and each time have Front make login, update the boolean to ***true***, and when logging-out update the boolean to ***false***.

But I have a problem with sessions. If a user does not log-out (the application is left open in the background), but the token expires, how can I control this?

Is there a simpler way to control user ***states***?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your issue to be related to your client not using refresh-token to renew access-token before it expires. [Serious client libs](https://openid.net/developers/certified/) do so.

Frequently, OpenID resource-servers are session-less: **user state from JWT access-token only**.

You can have a look at those tutorials which setup various spring-boot resource servers: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials

If user is "disconnected" client should send request without authorization header (or invalid token) and spring security context will be populated with `AnonymousAuthenticationToken` (if anonymous was enabled in your conf) => access will only be allowed if request path is configured with `permitAll()`.

If user is connected, client OpenID lib should maintain valid access-token (with the help of refresh-token).